# How do I exactly calculate the amount of heat generated in MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, heat, thermal

I am using two IRFP260N MOSFETs ([datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91215/91215.pdf)) in parallel for my application. I am using it to drive a motor rated at 24VDC and consumes 8 to 10 Amps. I found some answers here and calculated the temperature accordingly using the formula:

Id^2.Rds.Rθja

4^2 x 0.055 x 40 = 35.2'C

The result would be 60.2'C considering an ambient temperature of 25'C.

But when practically using the circuit produces no heat at all, maybe a couple of deg. C.
Before using IRFP260, I used 3xIRFP450 ([datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91233/91233.pdf)) with heatsink which produced decent amount(70+'C) of heat for 4 minutes of operation. Am I missing something?

Comment: First of all, you use the **max** value of Rds(on), so the typical value is lower. Next, this value applies to the **test conditions**. Check the graphs to find the Rdson of your application.

Comment: Third, you are using junction-ambient thermal resistance. There will be heat extracted via the leads so depending on specifics of your build your thermal resistance could be alot lower

Comment: And also the max value of Rθja

Comment: Are you leaving the mosfets on or using PWM? What is your gate voltage?

Comment: Are you still using a heat sink?

Comment: I am just leaving the MOSFET on for now to calculate the worst case in heating. I am not using a heat sink, it doesn't heat up at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power generated in the MOSFET will be

P = I x I x Rds

10A x 10A x 0.055 ohm (max) = 5.5W for one, so 2.75W for two in parallel.

The 0.055ohm is with 28A, could be less with only 5A.

You can find MOSFETs with even lower Rds, such as AOD508, with

Rds of 3 mOhm @ 20A, 10V

10*10*.003 = 300mW generated power to dissipate.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=aod508

Comment: Thanks, I know that the Rds is variable but I did not know it might be lower than the datasheet specifications.